# Kahler manifolds with special submanifolds

Tags: complex-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

This question is related to another question of mine.
Let $X$ be a kahler manifold with $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(X)=n$,
let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a holomorphic vector bundle of
$rank_{\mathbb{C}}(E)=n-k$ over a kahler manifold $M$ with
$\dim(M)=k$. Suppose there is a holomorphic embedding $\Phi$ of 
a neighborhood $N$ of the zero section of $E$ in $X$ that is 
$$\Phi:N\rightarrow X$$

What can be said about $X$?
If $M$ is a point nothing, but what if $M$ is a higher dimensional manifold?

Comment: Dear Italo, it would be nice if you can give a hint on the "type" of statement that you would like to have, i.e. give a slightly more specific question. At least, do you encounter such situations naturally?

Comment: I know that the question is rather vague, i imagined a situation like this thinking about my last question and your answer, in particular van de ven theorem. I was wondering if situations like the one described above are "natural" or conditions above are quite restrictive (as i suspect). And as consequence of the rigidity there is a statement like this: if you have a kahler manifold $X$ a vector bundle $E$ as above necessarily X is isomorphic $\mathbb{P}(E\osum \mathcal{L})$ with $\mathcal{L}$ a line bundle. 

Answer (score 3):

I would like to make one guess concerning one particular situation.

**Correction** *In fact, the following guess is **wrong** (thanks to jvp)! But I don't want to delete this answer, since jvp left a comment to it with a cool link, that shows why the guess is wrong*

**Guess.** Suppose that $M\cong \mathbb CP^1$, and $E=O(1)\oplus...\oplus O(1)$. In this case $X$ is rational, i.e. birational to $\mathbb CP^n$.

I have to say that I don't know how to prove this guess and even not 100% sure that this guess is correct. But first of all, this statement is obviously true if $n=2$ and I rather belive it should be possible to prove this for $n=3$ using twistor theory. The reason to make this guess is that if you have such a line in $X$ you can start to deform it and it deforms (at least locally) in exactly the same way as a line in $\mathbb CP^n$. Also, it is obvious that $X$ is rationally connected in this case.

Of course, this guess is a pure speculation. But maybe someone can prove it? :)

*Remark 1.* You can always blow up something in $X$ that does not touch the image of the zero section of $N$, so one can only say something (if one can at all) about birational type of $X$.

*Remark 2.* Note that if you don't assume $X$ to be Kaehler, but only ask it to be complex, then the *guess* is completely wrong. There exist huge amount of complex 3-folds containing lines with neighborhoods biholomorphic to a neighbourhood of a line in $\mathbb CP^3$. Such examples come from twistor theory -- one should take the twistor space of a conformally flat 4-manifold.

Comment: Related paper http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0304/0304006v1.pdf

Comment: Due to Campana:A twistor space of a compact, connected, oriented, conformally flat, even-dimensional Riemannian manifold, it is equivalent to be rational, unirational, Moishezon, simply connected or bimeromorphic to a compact Kähler manifold (i.e. in Fujiki's class $\mathcal C$).

Answer (score 2):

If your $X$ is projective and $E$ is an ample vector bundle over $M$ then the field of meromorphic functions of $X$ is a finite  extension of the field of meromorphic functions of $\mathbb P(E \oplus \mathcal O_M )$. This follows from Corollary 6.8 of Hartshorne's [Cohomological dimension of algebraic varieties](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1970720?origin=crossref).

There is also an analytic version by [Andreotti](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=BSMF_1963__91__1_0), which precedes Hartshorne's paper, 
implying the same result.